# PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class ChargeBee_Result could not be converted to string in Chargebee?

Tags: php

I have been trying to add new customer in Chargebee. But I got an error while echo the object.

Its my PHP script

```
 <?php
    require 'lib/ChargeBee.php';
    require 'chargebee_config.php';
            $result = ChargeBee_Customer::create(array(
              "firstName" => "Test", 
              "lastName" => "Test1", 
              "phone" => "987-987-9879",
              "company" => "Techcomp",
              "email" => "techEmail@gmail.com"
            ));
            $customer = $result->customer();
            echo $result;
    ?>
```

ERROR

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class ChargeBee_Result could not be
>   converted to string in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Signup\Customer_cBee.php on
>   line 28

Comment: `print_r($result);` instead `echo` if you just want to check what it returns. The point is, you can not echo object. Only string can be echo.

Comment: I would say that `$result->customer()` returns a Customer Object and not a string. Try using `print_r($result)` or `print_r($customer);` which I assume is what you intended to do

Comment: Well, yes? `echo $result;` ... `$result` is a `ChargeBee_Result` object if it doesn't have a `__toString()` method that's what you'd expect. Try `print_r()` or `var_dump()` instead of `echo` if you're debugging.